Can we give an accurate definition of the standard model of natural numbers within first-order logic and avoid the problem in Gödel first theorem?
I'm self-studying a mathematical logic book that eventually proves Gödel's first incompleteness theorem. Before I fully delve into the details, may I ask a high-level question?
The first incompleteness theorem implies the existence of nonstandard models of natural numbers that satisfy Peano's axioms, which, in my opinion, means Peano's axioms (within first-order logic) cannot fully characterize natural numbers in the usual sense. Then, can we replace these axioms with a more precise definition of natural numbers? For example, I believe Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory is within the framework of first-order logic. Can we then replace Peano's axioms with the set-theoretic definition of natural numbers? That is,
$ 0=\emptyset, 1=\{0\}, 2=\{0,1\},...$
In this way, there is a unique model of natural numbers so the problem raised in Gödel's first incompleteness theorem can be avoid?

The first incompleteness theorem exactly implies that you cannot do this (in first-order logic), since any such axioms are either also subject to the incompleteness theorem, or are not consistent, or are not computable! Getting unique models is also impossible for an easier reason, namely upward Lowenheim-Skolem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem
